# PhpStorm can't remember the Opening project in a new window setting

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

I'm not sure if the functionality has been disabled in the latest version but just to double check, I'm NOT seeing the "Remember do not ask again" option when I open another project in PhpStorm.

This is causing PhpStorm to ask me again and again if I want to open a project in new window every or same window, every single time.

I couldn't find anything in the settings either. How do I stop it from asking me and use my default (like before)?

Thanks.

Old dialog box:

[image: Old dialog box]

New dialog box (how do I make it remember?):

[image: New dialog box]

Comment: *I personally* think this is unlikely to happen. The *possible* reason is: now you can attach another project to the current one [WI-15187](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187). Without asking ... it would not be possible to do that ... or it will always open new project as part if another (or stuff like that). In any case: this ticket seems to be the most relevant (even though it's for another product -- the code is shared between all IDEs): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17836

Comment: Oh okay. It was a really useful feature but thanks for explaining why the changes were made.

Answer (score 5):

Since PhpStorm 2016.3.2, you can configure this via settings:

> In Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings, Project Opening, choose 'Open project in new window'